# Adding strings to javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
array = {};

function add(group,to_add){

    var index,to_append = "";

    if(array[group] === null || array[group] === undefined){
        array[group] = [to_add];
        index = array.length;
        if(index != 0)
            index = array.length--;
    }else{
        array[group].push(to_add);
        index = array.indexOf(group)--;
    }

}
```

After `add("some_group","something")` and doing `console.log(array)` the array logs as empty and I can't understand why... can someone help me on this one? Tyvm

### EDIT

WAIT GUYS after all I had array={} correct. The error is still on :'x

### CHAPTER 3: The mistery deepens

Guys, with the code above I got it to work **only if the array isn't empty previously**, so it actually works if array is `{ some_key: Array[1] }`. Any ideas on why? xD **'GROUP' is different from 'some_key', so the group is "new"**

Comment: It looks like you need to brush up on the difference between arrays and objects.

Comment: Using a array as associative is not possible, try an JSON-Object {}.

Comment: @AndreCalenta could you provide an example of what you are expecting the `array` to look like when you `console.log` it?

Comment: Just to be clear, `{}` is *not* a "JSON-Object".

Comment: What is `index` meant to be doing?

Comment: You're going to have to show a complete example that demonstrates the problem you're having, including example data and expected output, and it needs to be complete enough that people can try it for themselves.

Comment: I can't repro th problem with the code you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/5a10q48w/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array's are number indexed and can't be accessed like that

```
var array = [];
array[0] = 'something';
```

In your case you need a object

```
var obj = {};
obj['name'] = 'dave';
```

Be aware though that your code will now give NaN for length, as objects don't have a length property (so array.length wont work, giving you NaN when you try to increment/decrement it)

You need to do `Object.keys(obj).length` to get the length

i.e `Object.keys({name:'bob'}).length` will give a length of 1

Comment: Lol this is so bad, I got mixed up between languages. Thanks everyone (I can't accept your answer now, I'll do it later)

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to us all if we regularly switch languages

Comment: after all I had it right in the declaration, look at the edit please :x

Comment: This is not what the OP is trying to do. They want an object in this structure: `{ "group_name": ["a", "b"] }`

Comment: @atmd see question please

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Andy's answer, it can be boiled down ever further:

```
var data = {};

function add(group, value) {
    data[group] = data[group] || [];
    data[group].push(value);
}
```

### Why your code is failing

Really, this line is causing you the problems:

```
    if(index != 0)
        index = array.length--;
```

Using the decrement operator on `array.length` causes the array to drop the last value you just pushed. This is also why your code is only failing when the array is empty because you don't decrement `array.index` if the array already exists.

### Encapsulating this in a class

Why not make this an object singleton, or better yet a class?

```
function DataStore(data) {
    this.data = data || {};
}

DataStore.prototype = {

    constructor: DataStore,

    add: function(group, value) {
        this.data[group] =  this.data[group] || [];

        return this.data[group].push(value) - 1;
    },

    contains: function(group, value) {
        if (!this.containsGroup(group)) {
            return false;
        }

        return this.data[group].indexOf(value) > -1;
    },

    containsGroup: function(group) {
        return this.data.hasOwnProperty(group);
    },

    forEach: function(callback, context) {
        context = context || this;

        var key, index, value, length;

        for (key in this.data) {
            if (this.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                for (index = 0, length = this.data[key].length; i < length; i++) {
                    value = this.data[key][index];

                    if (callback.call(context, value, index, key) === false) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    get: function(group, index) {
        if (!this.containsGroup(group)) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (index == null) {
            return this.data[group];
        }
        else if (index >= 0 && index < this.data[group].length) {
            return this.data[group][index];
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    },

    remove: function(group, value) {
        if (!this.containsGroup(group)) {
            return -1;
        }

        var index = this.data[group].indexOf(value);

        this.data[group].splice(index, 1);

        return index;
    }

};
```

Then to use it:

```
// An empty DataStore:
var data = new DataStore();

data.add("group", "value");
data.containsGroup("group"); // returns true
data.contains("group", "value"); // returns true;

data.forEach(function(value, index, group) {
    console.log(group + "[" + index + "] = " + value);
}); 

// Seed the data store with values:
var data2 = new DataStore({
    foo: ["bar", "baz"]
});

data2.contains("foo", "baz"); // returns true;
```

Comment: I'm having trouble working out what the hell `index` is doing, if anything at all, in the OP's code.

Comment: @GregBurghardt see question please

Comment: @AndreCalenta: The reason your code isn't working is because you are decrementing the `array.index` value. This effectively _removes the last item you pushed from the array_.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to write something like this? It creates an object. If the key doesn't exist it's added with an array as the value. Then the second argument is added to the array.

```
var obj = {};

function add(group, to_add) {
  if (!obj[group]) obj[group] = [];
  obj[group].push(to_add);
}

add("some_group","something");
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly that but it can't be a short if due to some following code which might change that same key property of the object. What is wrong with my code, at all?

Comment: @AndreCalenta, beyond what I've answered I'm afraid I have no idea what your code is meant to do, or what the current problem is. Sorry.